# wkhtmltopdf running on Heroku worker timing out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, heroku, wkhtmltopdf

I have PDFs that I need to convert from html in my rails app that include both headers and footers. This has left me with wkhtmltopdf (if there's another option, please let me know!) For smaller PDFs, this solution worked fine - but larger PDFs became a problem. I now use a delayed_job worker to run this conversion in the background on a hobby worker dyno - and it takes a while, but works.... sometimes. For larger PDFs (or those with lots of images), I never get the result. Digging into the logs for the worker, I see the following:

```
2017-05-05T03:36:18.164514+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process running mem=666M(130.1%)
2017-05-05T03:36:18.164514+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2017-05-05T03:36:37.951774+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process running mem=804M(157.0%)
2017-05-05T03:36:37.951813+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2017-05-05T03:36:57.964496+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process running mem=944M(184.6%)
2017-05-05T03:36:57.964542+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2017-05-05T03:37:37.826785+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process running mem=1040M(203.2%)
2017-05-05T03:37:37.826861+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)
2017-05-05T03:37:37.826932+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-05-05T03:37:37.985631+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 137
2017-05-05T03:37:37.998614+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2017-05-05T03:37:38.000020+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-05-05T03:37:45.825684+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `rake jobs:work`
2017-05-05T03:37:46.532529+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-05-05T03:37:50.758067+00:00 app[worker.1]: [Worker(host:a5db76f8-58b3-4585-b664-eee04efb8a96 pid:4)] Starting job worker
2017-05-05T03:37:50.758157+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2017-05-05T03:37:50.758063 #4]  INFO -- : 2017-05-05T03:37:50+0000: [Worker(host:a5db76f8-58b3-4585-b664-eee04efb8a96 pid:4)] Starting job worker
```

I'm clearly running into a memory wall (not sure how to fix this without buying a much more expensive dyno), but I think thats okay... it should just page out to disk and take a lot longer, right? I have a private instance set up on cloud9 with the same configuration, and this is what it does there. Is there any way to set up paging options?

So what can I do? I don't care if the PDF takes 2-3 minutes to generate, I just don't want to get terminated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which Ruby version are you using? If you are running below 2.1, you definitely should upgrade to higher version.

Heroku's official guide explains about the memory issues, the same error you got in details, explaining possible fixes. I think this is the best resource you can get!

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-memory-use

You can also use SideKiq gem to move the pdf generation to the background job, so it won't throw heroku's time out error. However, you will have to upload the pdf file to the cloud server like Amazon S3.